# Enabling HTTP 1.1 in Internet Explorer 2.0

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, http, windows-nt-4

I am using Windows NT 4.0 and the built-in web browser Internet Explorer 2.0 seems to have a problem locating most of the web sites. It looks like the browser is not using HTTP/1.1 and doesn't pass the Host header to the server. This causes the server to response with 403 or other error. Or at least this is my current hypothesis of the situation. How can I enable HTTP/1.1. According to Wikipedia it should be supported.

Comment: I am not convinced that IE 2.0 even supports it.  There is no citation on that claim.  I suggest you find an alternative browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

HTTP/1.1 was ratified in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) in June, 1999. Internet Explorer 2.0 was released on [November, 22 1995](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_2); three and half years before HTTP/1.1 was invented. As such, it knows nothing about it and thus *cannot* support it.

Your best bet is simply to update to a newer version of IE. Service-pack 6 for NT4 [includes IE 6.0 SP1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_4.0#Features). You should apply the latest/last service-pack (SP6a) to NT4 anyway, so getting HTTP/1.1 through an IE upgrade is just another benefit of doing so.